# centos mysqld and httpd do not work at the same time

Tags: mysql, apache, centos

This problem happens suddenly and could not fix by rebooting.

The apache run very slow when both mysql and apache run at the same time.
When I check the mysqld status, it said mysqld dead but subsys locked.

Apache works fine when mysql is stopped.
Mysql also works fine when apache is stopped.

So what is the problem?

Comment: Who knows what the problem is... Sorry you don't provide any details or any indication as to your setup... You should have a read of the [help] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Need Complete details of your issue including version you are using of os and LAMP.

However you specified your mysqld status shows "mysqld dead but subsys locked".
you should investigate issue:

Same error i faced earlier and how i fixed that:

**Investigate log files:**

I checked my mysqld log files and found that the mysqld service was malfunctioning due to low memory.

cat /var/log/messages | grep mysqld | less

To check further events of mysqld , you can check mysqld.log using the following command:

cat /var/log/mysqld.log | less

In my case, I found the mysqld service was panicking and got shutdown due to memory problems.

Check if swap is present or not:
Run the below command to check if you have swap on your Linux Os.

free -m

if in swap option, you found 0 then it means you don't have swap memory in your system.

**Solution:**

To resolve this issue, we need to create a swap file, mount it and make it persistent on boot.

**Create swap file (8GB)**: pls note (Swap mamory should be double of your installed RAM), suppose you have 4 gb RAM then you should create 8 GB Swap.

Type the following commands to create and activate the swap.

dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8192

mkswap /swapfile

Finally, type the following command and hit Enter.

swapon /swapfile

**Secure the swapfile:**

To secure the swapfile from unauthorized access, type the following commands:

chown root:root /swapfile
chmod 600 /swapfile

Make swap persistent on boot:
vi /etc/fstab

Add the following at the end of the fstab file:
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0

Save and exit the file. Press ESC  and then type :wq and hit Enter.

You can run the command below to check if swap is active or not.
free -m

the swap of size 8142MB is activated. It would use the swap file whenever necessary.

**Restart / Start mysqld service:**

You can type the following command to start the mysql service.

service mysqld start

You should now be able to access your website.  Cheers :)